# Are there any stats about ubuntu touch sales?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was wondering if there's some where we can find how many bq and meizu units where sold, the activity of those users, downloaded apps, feedback, etc.

I'd really like to know how is Ubuntu touch doing with real users, besides reviews..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meizu phone has not been released yet, so the number of those units sold would be 0.

However, the sales are not via Canonical or Ubuntu sites. It is up to the manufacturers if they wish to post sales/return rates for the phones.